# Rails and Amazon CloudFront: How to cache background-images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

How can I attach background-image (in the .scss file) to the asset pipeline?

(I am trying to make Amazon CloudFront cache the images on CDN. But `config.action_controller.asset_host` only caches assets from the asset pipeline (as far as I have understood?))

Comment: I don't think I've ever had to do anything special for this to work (other than using asset-url and so on rather than hardcoding the full URL)

Comment: Of course! You are totally right, `image-url` was the solution (I had `background-image: url(/assets/image.jpg);`, but `background-image: image-url('image.jpg');` did the trick). Put it in an answer and I'll accept ;)